# "private method `split' called for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so in my rails project. I'm getting this error, any help?

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

def index
  @show_info
end
def do_search

    @show = params{:search_term}
    @show = @show["search_term"]
    @url = "http://services.tvrage.com/tools/quickinfo.php?show=#{@show}"

    @sitehtml = open(@url)

    lines = @sitehtml.split("\n")

    @show_info = []
    lines.each do |line|
        line_split = line.split("@")
        @show_info << line_split[1]
    end
end
end
```

and I keep on getting this error, [image: error]
(Full Size: http://grab.by/6z6u )

Any help? I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you're attempting to split isn't a String, it's a StringIO. Try doing `.string.split` on the offending object instead.

Comment: There we go! Thanks! I forgot to add the .read on "open(@url)

Answer (score 2):

StringIO does not have a public `split` method.  So, call `string` to get the underlying string.

```
lines = @sitehtml.string.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the error! I forgot to put the .read on on "open(@url)" to make it "open(@url).read". Thanks guys!